# How to scale websocket clients with queues

Tags: node.js, websocket, azure-web-app-service, message-queue

I am working with a third party API that supplies hotel information; one of the options it provides is a websocket notification when someone makes a booking, so by creating a client and receiving the broadcast message, I know when to go to the API's endpoints and get all the information about the booking.  For now I just want to write the messages to a queue.  I have written a simple node.js web app using the 'ws' library, that takes websocket messages and writes them to an Azure storage queue:

```
// Import the libraries I need for websockets, Azure storage queues and some config files
const env = require('dotenv').config();
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const config = require('./config');
const { QueueClient } = require('@azure/storage-queue');

var queueName, createQueueResponse, fullUrl, sendMessageResponse;

let connectionString = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;

// Get wss://clientsite URL and query string parameters from a config file
const { url: { site, myToken, hotelToken } } = config;

// Create a name for the queue. 
queueName = process.env.HOTEL_ID;

// Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to create and manipulate a queue
var queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);

// Create the queue
(async () => {
     createQueueResponse = await queueClient.createIfNotExists();
     if (createQueueResponse.requestId) {
         console.log("Queue created, requestId =", createQueueResponse.requestId);
     }
     else {
         console.log("Queue not created");
     }
 })();

//Create the websocket
 fullUrl = `${site}?ClientToken=${myToken}&AccessToken=${hotelToken}`;
 var ws = new WebSocket(fullUrl);

//Write the received messages to the queue   
ws.on('message', async function incoming(data) {
     if (data) {
         sendMessageResponse = await queueClient.sendMessage(data);
         console.log("Messages added, requestId:", sendMessageResponse.requestId);
     }
});

ws.on('error', function error(error) {
     console.log("Error: " + error.message);
});
```

But I want to be able to listen out for messages from potentially hundreds of websockets and keep track of which source was which, maybe by linking each websocket to a different queue.  But when I try this by iterating over a list of websocket URLs, creating a queue for each of them, they all end up using the final queue I created.

What is the correct way to bind a websocket client to a queue, scaleably?  I have looked into using SignalR but all the examples are for how to create a chatroom!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps have set service limits per SKU, which includes caps on the number of websockets and memory. You can see them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits). Even though standard tier SKUs have unlimited web sockets, you will hit up against memory limits at a certain point. You can potentially scale further by provisioning multiple Web App instances, up to 10 for the standard tier.

After playing around with this problem for four years or so, we scaled out of self-hosting websockets and went with the SignalR service. You can have connected clients running into the hundreds of thousands with SignalR service. I highly recommend using it to save yourself a bunch of headaches.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but how do I use SignalR as a websocket client, can you point me at any examples?  I need to work with a 3rd party who are publishing messages using websockets.  This is more important than whether or not we use Azure.